# How to force excel file to open in browser instead of download?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working with MVC5 Crystal reports of pdf and excel files, my code works well for pdf to view in the web browser but when i change content-type to excel file its download only,

```
public ActionResult Summary(string startDate, string endDate, string summaryBy, string reportType)
    {
        using (MMTModel entity = new MMTModel())
        {
            string CryRpt_Name = null;
            ObjectResult<DeeqtoonSummary> ObjRsl = null;
            if (reportType == "Summary")
            {
                CryRpt_Name = "Summary.rpt";
                ObjRsl = entity.rpt_Summary(startDate, endDate, summaryBy);
            }
            else if (reportType == "Detail")
            {
                CryRpt_Name = "Detail.rpt";
                ObjRsl = entity.rpt_Detail(startDate, endDate);
            }

            ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
            rpt.Load(Path.Combine(rpt.FileName = Server.MapPath("~/CrystalReports"), CryRpt_Name));

            List<Summary> ObjRslLst = ObjRsl.ToList();
            rpt.SetDataSource(ObjRslLst);
            try
            {
                //Excel file
                Stream stream = rpt.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.Excel);
                return File(stream, "application/vnd.ms-excel");

                //pdf file
                Stream stream = rpt.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
                return File(stream, "application/pdf");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can i force to open the excel file in the web browser?

Comment: What operating system and web browser are you using? If you're on Windows, you could set the `.exe` file of the browser as the default PDF viewer.

Comment: @Nick B. OP's problem isn't with viewing PDF in the browser, it is with excel documents.

Comment: I am using Window7 as OS and Google Chrome as web browser

Comment: Chrome out-of-the-box doesn't have an option to edit any specific file type (eg excel) in the browser, so will always attempt to download it.  Your user can change PDF option to always download as well.  There's no way to "force" chrome to open any file in the browser as it's a user-specific option.  If I was your user, I'd be very annoyed that it opened in the browser.  Assuming this is for you alone, you could install a 3rd-party extension of which there are plenty in the Chrome webstore (just google for "excel chrome").

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about crystal-reports, but if your browser doesn't have an implementation for viewing excel documents then it will just download them. I have never been able to open an excel document with my browser unless the web application itself implements the display of the document.

Basically, you have to implement the MVC that displays an excel document yourself. Your browser doesn't support it out of the box.